# undefined method `call' for :err:Symbol after bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

After pulling my application, I noticed I had to run bundle install (I'm using rails 3 and ruby 1.9 at Ubuntu 10.10).

Bundler indicated a gem conflict and told me to bundle update. After that, my application broke giving me the following error:

https://gist.github.com/979975

At config/environment.rb:5, I only have

TopTal::Application.initialize!

I reinstalled rvm, ruby, ran bundle install again but the error still appears here. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with "bundle update"! When you ran it, bundler ignored the previously installed gems in Gemfile.lock and updated many or all of your gems. I suggest you revert your  Gemfile and Gemfile.lock back to before you did the update and try bundle install again. Note the gem with the conflict and then do "bundle update gem_name". This should update only the gem with the problem.